# Are questions about the Windows 8 upgrade offer too localized?

Tags: discussion, too-localized

There are quite a lot of questions about the Windows 8 upgrade. You could reason that (some) of these questions are too localized as the offer expires at the 31st of Januari 2013.

I just asked the following question: [In what timezone did the deadline for the cheap Windows 8 upgrade fall?](https://superuser.com/q/543931/18490)

Which could be considered a good candidate for too localized. However I mentioned "You could reason that if for example there is a similar offer for Windows 9. That it might be relevant to know what the case was for Windows 8".

I'm not sure if that reason holds up, but I thought I'd put it up for discussion here on meta so that we can determine where the border lies.

(Maybe the title of this question should be made broader to cover all questions about such upgrades or new releases).

Comment: I agree the question is too localized to a specific point in time, but it's probably a useful question before the offer expires, so doesn't necessarily have to be closed *yet*. Consider people who have the same issue—in many cases. "Too localized" generally shouldn't be used if you could imagine there are others who might have the same problem, which applies in this case.

Comment: With a similar argument we could have closed *all* questions about the Windows 8 Consumer Preview because we knew it'd become irrelevant after some time.

Comment: @slhck you could reason that some questions about the offer could be relevant later. For example, if you have a key purchased through that offer and a few years later you can't seem to get it activated, then a question about the conditions are still relevant.

Comment: @slhck: technically that was the idea behind having seperate tags for previews.

Comment: @MatthijsWessels - I would argue that only means the existing qustions should not be deleted. Many of the questions about the upgrade offer I have seen in the last 4 months were about the process of using the upgrade license ( i.e what made you eligible for the upgrade license ). As for the question being able to be applied to Windows 9 this assumes there will be a similar offer even offered in the future. Of course it was discovered the Microsoft uses localized regional pages, so the information when this offer expires, is defined on those pages.